# How to check if remote stream file exists

Tags: php

#### PHP

```
$url = 'http://example.mp3';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($retcode); echo '</pre>';
```

This is my code check if remote file exists, if it's a real mp3 file, it will return the right code 200 or something, but if the mp3 is create by streaming, some server will return 0, some will return 501, how to check if streaming file is not dead?

Comment: 0 is not any http code, you can check for content-length header of response

Comment: Please tell me how to do, thanks

Comment: Because of you clue, I use `get_headers` function to check the file, and it works perfectly, thanks